# How to disable required attributes MVC model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a model :

```
[Range(1, 24, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Hour")]
public int val1{ get; set; }

[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
public string val2 { get; set; }
```

I have a edit action also I have view page. There are 2 textboxes `val1.text, val2.text` if I write fill view form (I am not writing any value on `val1`) return InvalidHour. I want to give ability to set empty value (not writing something on val1). PROBLEM on val1 return Invalid Hour when empty! can i give empty?

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it a nullable int

```
[Range(1, 24, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Hour")]
public int? val1{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer is a primitive data type. Try to make it nullable with `int?`